# How can i code my program that if any input is given it outputs associated code

Tags: c++

How can I code my program that if any input is given it outputs associated code?
And if you don't input anything it displays the associated code.
I am trying to make a program that lets you enter the car if you enter your license number.
Code:

```
#include<iostream>

using namespace std;
int main()
{
    int age,b;
    cout<<"Please Enter your Age: "<<endl;
    cin>>age;
    
    if(age<18)
    {
        cout<<"Sorry You can't Enter the car!"<<endl;
    }
    else if(age>=18)
    {
        cout<<"Firstly Show your driving license number: "<<endl;
        cin>>b;
        if(b==1)
        {
        cout<<"Thank you for showing your license number"<<endl;
        }
        else if(b!=1)
        {
            cout<<"your license number is wrong"<<endl;
        }
    }
    else if((age<=17) && (age>=1))
    {
        cout<<"you are not qualified for a license"<<endl;
    }
    else if(age>=20)
    {
        cout<<"you have a license"<<endl;
        cin>>b;
    

        if(b==2)
        {
            cout<<"you can enter in the car"<<endl;
        }
    }
    
    switch(age)
        default:
        {
            cout<<"please don't mind this is the rule of government"<<endl;
        }
    
    
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: what is "the associated code" ? Please edit the question to add example input, desired and actual output

Comment: The first two conditions (`age < 18` and `age >= 18`) cover all possibilities - you will never reach the last two conditions.

Comment: What is the problem you are having with this code?

Comment: odd use of `switch(age)`

Comment: @AlanBirtles i want that if i give any input it display thanks for showing your license.

Comment: @molbdnilo so how can i fix that?

Comment: @MuhammadArslanNazir You think about the logic and perform your tests in the appropriate order.